# blender won't allow me to sculpt anything

Tags: sculpting

I haven't been able to find much on this nor does uninstalling and reinstalling work. Also when i try and import brushes theyre all greyed out like this and even the default one doesn't work. Someone asked me if my version is pirated and no its legit. pls help [image]

Comment: FYI Blender is a free and open source program - there is no such thing as a "pirated version" as far as I'm aware. As for the brushes, where did you get them - are you sure they're compatible with blender 2.83 and above?

Comment: that "someone" isn't an expert - that's for sure...